# How do I create a One-to-One relationship in Entity Framework 4

Tags: entity-framework-4

I am struggling to create a One-to-One relationship in EF4.I keep getting errors like this:

`Each of the following columns in table XXX is mapped to multiple conceptual side properties:
XXX.Id is mapped to <XXXYYY.YYY.YYYId, XXXYYY.XXX.Id>`

Given I have a classes `Person` and `PersonDetail` that relate to tables of the same name, and the Id's are the same in both tables (I think EF4 assumes this as default?) What do I do in my edmx files to define this relationship?

I only need `Person` have a `PersonDetail` property, not the other way round.

Comment: Do both tables have primary keys?

Comment: Yes both tables have a primary key? `PersonDetail`'s primary key is also implicitly a foreign to `Person`

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem and it seems that the answer is to introduce a referential constraint. See Step 5 in the link below.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2008/12/05/table-splitting-mapping-multiple-entity-types-to-the-same-table.aspx

If you are using EF4 and Visual Studio 2010 you don't need to edit the xml - you can just double-click on the join in the designer to set the constraint. After doing this, you can optionally delete the mapping if you have already set it.